# Manage hover and click behaviour of nested navbar on both desktop and mobile [HTML / CSS]

Tags: html, css, mobile, navigationbar

I am trying to fix the behaviour of a nested navbar I have on my page. The main idea is that I have two levels of `<ul>`-tags, where on both levels the `<li>`-tags can contain links (i.e. `<a>`), so both levels have the ability to redirect the page. Upon hovering the top level `<li>`, I have the lower level display, otherwise it is hidden. This looks like this:

```css
* {
  font-family: Roboto;
}

.menu-container {
  height: 29px;
  background-color: #dcb400;
}

.menu {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
}

.menu-item {
  position: relative;
}

.menu-item:hover {}

.menu-item-div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 0;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  padding: 3.5px 9.5px;
  color: black;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 13px;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 22px;
}

.menu-item:hover .menu-item-div {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.submenu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 29px;
  width: auto;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  z-index: 100;
  padding: 0px;
  display: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px rgb(0 0 0 / 50%);
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px rgb(0 0 0 / 50%);
}

.menu-item:hover .submenu {
  display: block;
}

.submenu-item {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.submenu-item:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class='menu-container'>
    <ul class='menu'>
      <li class='menu-item'>
        <a href='#'>
          <div class='menu-item-div'>Menu item 1</div>
        </a>
        <ul class='submenu'>
          <li class='submenu-item'>Submenu item 1</li>
          <li class='submenu-item'>Submenu item 2</li>
          <li class='submenu-item'>Submenu item 3</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class='menu-item'>
        <a href='#'>
          <div class='menu-item-div'>Menu item 2</div>
        </a>
        <ul class='submenu'>
          <li class='submenu-item'>Submenu item 4</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class='menu-item'>
        <a href='#'>
          <div class='menu-item-div'>Menu item 3</div>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

Now, this works like a charm on desktop, as my submenus show up as soon as I hover a top level menu item. However, on mobile this doesn't work anymore, as the only (reasonable) way to hover a top level menu item is by clicking it, which results in the page redirecting to the top level `<a>` target. Is there a way to expand this code to also make it work on mobile, i.e. when tapping the top level menu item on mobile, the submenu should show up instead of the page redirecting?

The solutions I have found so far online are either concerning libraries like bootstrap or are way too clumsy. I am wondering if there is a way to do this with only HTML and CSS, or do we also have to involve some js?

Comment: Please click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and post a [mcve] HERE at Strackoverflow since jsfiddles can get deleted or go stale.

Answer (score -2):

Since you are not using your top level menu items for redirecting, you could abandon your  references altogether and use divs instead:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <div>Menu item 1</div>
    <ul> <!-- display on hover of top level li -->
      <li><a>Submenu item 1</a></li>
      ...
    </ul>
  </li>
  ...
</ul>
```

Or for your given example: https://jsfiddle.net/0fmbojqk/3/

Comment: I am though, this does unfortunately not solve the problem, as you have just removed the `<a>` tags around my top level menu items, so on desktop the top level items will just not redirect anymore